# {"status":true,"message":"Number of messages on bulk (1016) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)\n"}

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, firebase, push-notification

i am getting this when i want to send push notifications to all users through firebase, I chunked array but getting same error. please help

```
 $noti_title = $request->notif_title;
        $noti_body = $request->notif_body;
        if ($request->notif_to == 1) {

            $all_users  = \App\User::orderBy('id','desc')->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $all_user = array_chunk($all_users, 600);
            $all_firebase_tokens = [];
            foreach($all_user as $numbers){
                foreach($numbers as $number){                   
                    array_push($all_firebase_tokens, \App\UserDeviceId::WhereIn('user_id',[$number])->pluck('firebase_token')->toArray());
                }
            }
                if(count($all_firebase_tokens) > 0) {
                    $message = [
                        "registration_ids" => $all_firebase_tokens,
                        "priority" => 'high',
                        "sound" => 'default',
                        "badge" => '1',
                        "data" =>
                        [
                            "title" => $noti_title,
                            "body"  => $noti_body,
                            "type" => 'Admin_notification',
                        ],
                        "notification" =>
                        [
                            "title" => $noti_title,
                            "body"  => $noti_body,
                            "type" => 'Admin_notification',
                        ]
                    ];
                  return \App\PushNotification::send($message);
                }
```

Comment: Divide your subscriber list into chunks of less than 1000(may be 999) as it doesn't support more than 1000 at a single instance.

Comment: sir please check my code i already chunked array into 600

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
        $all_firebase_tokens = [];
        foreach($all_user as $numbers){
            foreach($numbers as $number){                   
                array_push($all_firebase_tokens, \App\UserDeviceId::WhereIn('user_id',[$number])->pluck('firebase_token')->toArray());
            }
        }
```

You still have more when 600

Because `$all_firebase_tokens = [];` placed before nested foreach

Actually you can try something like this

```
foreach($all_user as $numbers){
    
    $all_firebase_tokens = [];
    foreach($numbers as $number){                   
        array_push($all_firebase_tokens, \App\UserDeviceId::WhereIn('user_id',[$number])->pluck('firebase_token')->toArray());
    }

    if(count($all_firebase_tokens) > 0) {
        $message = [
           "registration_ids" => $all_firebase_tokens,
           "priority" => 'high',
           "sound" => 'default',
           "badge" => '1',
           "data" =>
             [
               "title" => $noti_title,
               "body"  => $noti_body,
               "type" => 'Admin_notification',
             ],
               "notification" =>
             [
                "title" => $noti_title,
                "body"  => $noti_body,
                "type" => 'Admin_notification',
             ]
         ];
      return \App\PushNotification::send($message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, if below does not work, try using a `cron` job.

#### Possible issue

In the code you limit to `600` users, which is less than `1000`.

```
$all_user = array_chunk($all_users, 600);
```

But later your code iterates:

```
foreach($all_user as $numbers){
    foreach($numbers as $number){
```

> Meaning users can have multiple tokens.

If each user has just `2` numbers, we reach `600*2 = 1200` ;-)

### Solution

To see if I am right, simply try:

```
$all_user = array_chunk($all_users, 1);
```

Instead of:

```
$all_user = array_chunk($all_users, 600);
```

And improve your logic to chunk tokens, not users.

### Alternative

Chances are that above solution does not work, if so read below.

I am not sure about Firebase, but some API have time limits,
I mean, 1000 per second or even per day (instead of per request).

In such cases you would need to use a `cron` job.

See also: stackoverflow.com/[How to create PHP cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)